# BaseFieldControl in SPControlMode.Display not display correct values

Tags: spfield, display-form

I'm creating my own Display Form based on a view in a webpart. I'm getting the list (Document Library), and view, and then iterating through the fields, and creating a BaseFieldControl and then adding this control to the page. I'm finding that the display value always looks like the following:  ["Task Name" column value]

It doesn't display any value at all! For any type of field. Just the field Name, and the words column value afterwards. Has anyone else solved this problem?

My code is below.

```
 internal static Control GetSharePointControlsForDisplay(SPField field, SPList list, int itemId, System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        // check if the field is a buildIn field, or can be rendered by a SharePoint Control
        if (field == null || field.FieldRenderingControl == null || field.Hidden) return null;

        Control ctrl = null;

        var mode = SPControlMode.Display;


        var controlContext = SPContext.GetContext(context, itemId, list.ID, list.ParentWeb);

        SPContext.Current.FormContext.SetFormMode(mode, true);
        controlContext.FormContext.SetFormMode(mode, true);


        try
        {
                BaseFieldControl webControl = field.FieldRenderingControl;
                webControl.ListId = list.ID;
                webControl.ControlMode = mode;
                webControl.ItemId = itemId;
                webControl.FieldName = field.Title;
                webControl.ID = GetControlID(field);

                webControl.RenderContext = controlContext;
                webControl.ItemContext = controlContext;

                ctrl = webControl;
            }
            return ctrl;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errorLabel = new Label
            {
                ID = "ErrorLabel",
                Text = String.Format("Error in GetSharePointControls:<br/>{0}", ex)
            };
            return errorLabel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It appears to be a problem with my page, as this webpart works on other sites, and other pages. Need to find out what is different about the page I'm trying to put the webpart on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with reuse of the SPWeb (wrapped in SPContext) used by ItemContext and RenderContext I had a number of different problems including the one here, they all finally went away when I created my own SPWeb every time I need one.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(list.ParentWeb.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
    {
        SPContext renderContext = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current, itemId, list.ID, web);
        webControl.ItemContext = renderContext;
        webControl.RenderContext = renderContext;
        ...
    }
}
```

There is clearly going to be a performance penalty for creating all these SPWeb's this is not an issue for me however since my application will only be showing a few list items at a time. I wonder if there's a more economical way to clone the SPWeb in a satisfactory manner.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by user787070 helped me with a similar issue.

I have a web part that works more or less perfectly in SharePoint 2010 and onwards. However, when my BaseFieldControl derived controls use SPControlMode.Display - I get differing behaviour on certain pages, and differing behaviour in MOSS / SP2007.

In SP2010 the controls display the correct information from the correct item. However in MOSS / SP2007 I was getting "[*ColumnName* column value]" as the field value. Similar to what happens if you view EditForm.aspx without passing an ID. This turned out to be an issue with the SPContext I was creating.

Where I had:

```
 SPContext renderContext = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current, docLibrary.GetItemById(itemId).ID, docLibrary.ID, docLibrary.ParentWeb);
 control.ItemContext = renderContext;
 control.RenderContext = renderContext;
```

This worked fine in SP2010, but gave the aforementioned issue in 2007. By wrapping my code in a couple of usings, and opening the Web explicitly, this issue went away:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(docLibrary.ParentWeb.Url)) {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) {
       foreach(BaseFieldControl control in controlCollection) {
          SPContext renderContext = 
              SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current,
                 docLibrary.GetItemById(itemId).ID,
                 docLibrary.ID, 
                 web);
          control.ItemId = itemId;
          control.RenderingContext = renderContext;
          control.ItemContext = renderContext;
          // -- etc --
        }
     }
 }
```

Hopefully this helps someone else experiencing the same.